# Ubuntu 20.04 blacks out with kernels newer than 5.15.0-74-generic

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel

Ubuntu 20.04 blacks out at booting with kernels newer than 5.15.0-74.
Now I lock the kernel to 5.15.0-73-generic.

My hardwware is iMac 21 inch mid 2011 (CPU Core i3 540, 16GB DRAM).
The video driver shown by **lshw** is Mobility Radeon HD 4670.

After the drives are checked, the screen falls into blank state.
However, the system itself seems to boot normally.
I can ssh to it from other machines.

The followings are the outputs of `journalctl -b --no-pager | grep radeon` for the **latest kernel 5.15.0-84-generic** and the **old kernel 5.15.0-73-generic**.

With the latest kernel, **systemd** seems to stop **Screen Backlight Brightness**.

**5.15.0-84-generic**

```
Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: No more image in the PCI ROM

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 256M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000000FFFFFFF (256M used)

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000010000000 - 0x000000004FFFFFFF

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon: 256M of VRAM memory ready

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon: dpm initialized

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] enabling PCIE gen 2 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000010000c00

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000010000c0c

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x000000000005c598

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon: irq initialized.

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: [drm] fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device

Sep 24 21:33:13 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0

Sep 24 21:33:06 ubuntu2004-imac systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:radeon_bl0...

Sep 24 21:33:06 ubuntu2004-imac systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:radeon_bl0.

Sep 24 21:34:05 ubuntu2004-imac systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:radeon_bl0...

Sep 24 21:34:05 ubuntu2004-imac systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@backlight:radeon_bl0.service: Succeeded.

Sep 24 21:34:05 ubuntu2004-imac systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:radeon_bl0.
```

**5.15.0-73-generic**

```
Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: No more image in the PCI ROM

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 256M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000000FFFFFFF (256M used)

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000010000000 - 0x000000004FFFFFFF

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon: 256M of VRAM memory ready

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon: dpm initialized

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] enabling PCIE gen 2 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000010000c00

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000010000c0c

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x000000000005c598

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon: irq initialized.

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: [drm] fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device

Sep 24 21:35:27 ubuntu2004-imac kernel: [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0

Sep 24 21:35:17 ubuntu2004-imac systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:radeon_bl0...

Sep 24 21:35:17 ubuntu2004-imac systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:radeon_bl0.

Sep 24 21:36:11 ubuntu2004-imac /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2595]:         loading driver: radeon

Sep 24 21:36:11 ubuntu2004-imac /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2595]: (==) Matched radeon as autoconfigured driver 0

Sep 24 21:36:11 ubuntu2004-imac /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2595]: (II) LoadModule: "radeon"

Sep 24 21:36:11 ubuntu2004-imac /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2595]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so

Sep 24 21:36:11 ubuntu2004-imac /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2595]: (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
```

Comment: Radeon HD 4670 is from 2008, so I am surprized you get to check many drivers for it. Old AMD GPUs are supported by the `radeon` module, which should autoload. No proprietary driver is available, so there should be nothing to install, check or uncheck.

Comment: I have submitted this error to bugs.launchpad.net.